# How to count the number of occurrences in code?

Tags: python

I need to count number of each instance for second column in file that looks like this:

```
1234;'001';X
1234;'001';X
1234;'003';Y
1280;'001';X
1280;'002';Y
1280;'002';Y
1280;'003';X
```

I tried to solve the problem, but my code shows how many elements are in the input file.

```
import csv
from collections import Counter

#get line
with open('myFile.txt', 'r') as file:
    next(file) #skip header
        occurrence = Counter(tuple(row[1:2]) for row in csv.reader(file))
print(occurrence)



with open('myOutputFile.txt', 'w') as file2:
writer = csv.writer(file2)
writer.writerow(['Nr powiatu: ' 'Wystapienia: '])
for occur, count in occurrence.items():
    writer.writerow([occur, count])
```

The output I need is:
001 - 3
002 - 2
003 - 2

It's just the sum of specific occurrences in second column.
And my result is 7

Comment: Running you code with that example prints: `Counter({'001': 3, '003': 2, '002': 2})` for me.

Comment: Unforunately I only get:
Nr powiatu: Wystapienia: 

(),6

Anyway, Perplexabot helped me with that. It works perfectly - just as I want.
(Sorry for these polish words in code - 'Nr powiatu: ' 'Wystapienia: '. I completely forgot about them and it might look weird and incomprehensible for foreigners reading the code.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you need:

```
import csv
from collections import Counter

with open('myFile.txt', 'r') as fd:
    next(fd)
    occurrence = Counter([row[1] for row in csv.reader(fd, delimiter=';')])
print(occurrence)
```

I think you are missing the delimiter.

Comment: The `lst = []` is not needed, though.

Comment: You're great! Thanks Perplexabot and perennial_noob :)